# Spring batch chunk processing is going into infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have this weird case where spring batch chunk processing is going into infinite loop when encountered an exception during item read/write. When checked the stack trace there is an IOException. It happened for other runtime errors as well.

**Step Configurations :**

```
listener(new CustomStepExecutionListener(jobId))
    .chunk(chunkSize)
    .reader(csvReader(file))
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(writer(successRecordsWriter, failedRecordsWriter))
    .listener(new CustomWriteListener())
    .faultTolerant()
    .skip(FlatFileParseException.class)
    .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .listener(new CustomSkipListener(failedRecordsWriter))
    .listener(new CustomChunkListener())
    .stream(failedRecordsWriter)
    .build();
```

**CustomChunkListener**

```
  public class CustomChunkListener implements ChunkListener {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomChunkListener.class);
  private static final String CHUNK_NO = "CHUNK_NO";
  private int chunkCount = 0;

  public CustomChunkListener() {

  }

  @Override
  public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
    MDCContext.put(CHUNK_NO, String.valueOf(++chunkCount));
    context.setAttribute(CHUNK_NO, chunkCount);
    LOGGER.info("Chunk processing started. context = {}", context);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
    stopTheWatch();
    LOGGER.info("Chunk processing completed. context = {}", context);
    MDCContext.remove(CHUNK_NO);
    context.removeAttribute(CHUNK_NO);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterChunkError(ChunkContext context) {
    stopTheWatch();
    LOGGER.info("Chunk processing failed. context = {}", context);
    MDCContext.remove(CHUNK_NO);
    context.removeAttribute(CHUNK_NO);
  }

}
```

**Exception :**

```
    java.io.IOException: Stale file handle
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read(FileDispatcherImpl.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:201)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [file [/src/input.csv]]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:220)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:173)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:89)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:394)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor244.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
```

**Failure Logs**

The log lines from CustomChunkListener class are getting printed endlessly without actually reaching the writer class and CHUNK_NO is increased to a million whereas it should be ideally 1 or 2 based on our logic.

```
Chunk processing started. context = ChunkContext: attributes=[CHUNK_NO], complete=false, stepContext=SynchronizedAttributeAccessor: [], stepExecutionContext={FlatFileItemWriter.current.count=0, FlatFileItemWriter.written=0, batch.taskletType=org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet, FlatFileItemReader.read.count=0, batch.stepType=org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep}, jobExecutionContext={}, jobParameters={BATCH_ID=c8aad01f-7779-4574-b15c-337fbd0f32d6}

Chunk processing failed. context = ChunkContext: attributes=[CHUNK_NO], complete=true, stepContext=SynchronizedAttributeAccessor: [], stepExecutionContext={FlatFileItemWriter.current.count=0, FlatFileItemWriter.written=0, batch.taskletType=org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet, FlatFileItemReader.read.count=0, batch.stepType=org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep}, jobExecutionContext={}, jobParameters={BATCH_ID=c8aad01f-7779-4574-b15c-337fbd0f32d6}, Time Taken = 0 SECONDS
```

Why is the same chunk starting & failing multiple times even after the first failure ? How to avoid this behaviour when these kind of runtime errors occur ?

Comment: I have never seen this behaviour. If you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can debug the case.

Comment: Thanks for responding @MahmoudBenHassine. Am not able to reproduce this locally. Curious to know can this be a design issue ? we use a master-slave architecture for processing jobs. Master instances partitions the file and and sends them over queue (rabbitmq). Slaves pick these messages and process. Both masters and slaves refer a common nfs mount storage where the data files are located.